# how to calculate difference of two messages in callback function on same topic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, message, topic, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Sir,
I am actually reading my hand pose from a Leap Motion sensor and I want to calculate how much the hand moves in X direction.
My question is how to read the message in callback function(as you know, the message is coming through a normal topic ) and show the difference between the previous message and the current one?
Please take a look at my call back function:

```
public:
  spaceNavToTwist() : spinner_(1)
  {
    joy_sub_ = n_.subscribe("leapmotion/data", 1, &spaceNavToTwist::joyCallback, this);
    // Changed "spacenav/joy" to topic "/leapmotion/data"
    twist_pub_ = n_.advertise<geometry_msgs::TwistStamped>("jog_arm_server/delta_jog_cmds", 1);
    joint_delta_pub_ = n_.advertise<jog_msgs::JogJoint>("jog_arm_server/joint_delta_jog_cmds", 1);

    spinner_.start();
    ros::waitForShutdown();
  };

private:
  ros::NodeHandle n_;
  ros::Subscriber joy_sub_;
  ros::Publisher twist_pub_, joint_delta_pub_;
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner_;

    void joyCallback(const jog_msgs::leapros::ConstPtr& msg)
{
// Variables to store the previous values of handpose along X,Y and Z-Axes
double previousX, previousY, previousZ;
// Variables to store the current values of handpose along X,Y and Z-Axes
double currentX, currentY, currentZ;
// Get the initial values of handpose along X,Y and Z-Axes
previousX = msg->palmpos.x;
// Read the current values of handpose along X,Y and Z-Axes

currentX = msg->palmpos.x;
ROS_ERROR("previous %f", previousX);
ROS_ERROR("current %f", currentX);
ROS_ERROR("difference %f", currentX-previousX);
```

I don't know why when I print the previous message and the current one out, they are always the same and difference is 0.
Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311156/how-to-calculate-difference-of-two-messages-in-callback-function-on-same-topic/) by [stevensu1838](https://answers.ros.org/users/32486/stevensu1838/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is something wrong here :

```
// Get the initial values of handpose along X,Y and Z-Axes
previousX = msg->palmpos.x;
// Read the current values of handpose along X,Y and Z-Axes
currentX = msg->palmpos.x;
```

You are actually doing `previousX = currentX` since you assigned them the same value.

What you want to do is to use global variables so that when the callback is called again you still have the value stored somewhere, i'll give you an exemple :

```
//global variable that needs to be set to a default value
double previousX = 0;
void joyCallback(const jog_msgs::leapros::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    double difference;
    difference = msg->palmpos.x - previousX;
    ROS_INFO("previous %f", previousX);
    previousX = msg->palmpos.x;
    ROS_INFO("current %f", previousX);
    ROS_INFO("difference %f", difference);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevensu1838](https://answers.ros.org/users/32486/stevensu1838/) on 2018-12-22**:
Hi buddy, thank you so much for your help. And I am right now calculating the speed of my hand in the following link. Can you please take a look？[link](https://answers.ros.org/question/311345/put-data-from-one-topic-into-an-dynamic-array-in-the-callback-function-and-do-calculation-in-ros)